Seeking research and on how AI is impacting professions
I'm currently delving into a research project focused on understanding how artificial intelligence (AI) is reshaping professional fields and job roles. I'm particularly interested in the most recent studies and publications that discuss the implications of AI across various professions.
Could anyone recommend contemporary research papers, books, or resources that provide insights into the effects of AI on professional practices? I'm looking for materials that explore both the positive transformations and the challenges brought by AI integration into the workforce.
Additionally, if there are any notable authors or thought leaders in this field whose works you find invaluable, I'd appreciate your recommendations. I'm aiming to build a comprehensive understanding of the topic to inform a series of discussions and possibly a publication in the future.
Thank you in advance for your help!
